# Arranging different oxygen-containing organic compounds by decreasing acidity

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, acid-base

I am facing difficulty in the following problem.

> Arrange the following compound in decreasing order of acidity.
>
> [image: cyclohexanol, cyclopentylmethanoic acid, 3,3-dimethylpentan-2-one, 1,4-dioxane]

It is clear that conjugate base of (Q) is more stable.hence it is most acidic.in R) there is much steric hinderence so my view is that it should be less acidic.however I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is the type of question for which Professor Mayr made us chemistry students rote memorise typical $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values. Here are some.

\begin{array}{lc}\hline
\text{compound type} & \text{typical }\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}\\ \hline
\text{alcohol} & \approx 15 \\
\text{ketone} & \approx 20\\
\text{carboxylic acid} & \approx 5\phantom{0}\\
\text{secondary }\ce{C-H} & \approx 45\\ \hline\end{array}

Therefore, the order is $\mathrm{Q > P > R > S}$

Comment: why the downvote? I would agree with the answer. Carboxylic acids are undoubtedly more acidic than others here. A hydrogen attached to an Oxygen(in OH) should be more acidic than a H attached to a C (in ketone) and there is no reason for an ether to be acidic.